# Removing TeamFoundationServer DLLS from project .NET

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a project which use to be in TFS but now has migrated to mercurial.

After doing so we have noticed three DLL's being added to the solution on Build.

Apart from writing a script to delete the files at the end of a Build is there a way to remove TFS totally from a solution?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: What are these DLL's called?

Comment: Your projects shouldn't be connected to TFS dll's in any way. Maybe there is some pre/post build event or some unnoticed dependency that's has copy local flag set?

Comment: This is not a TFS / Non-TFS issue. TFS does not add any dependencies into your project.  I suspect that this is a build configuration issue.

Comment: I suspect there are some TFS build hooks being called by some code in your solution.  Figure out what the TFS namespaces are for those .dlls and try to find a class file that uses them.